# TFS 2015 Api Get build information

Tags: c#, tfs

For our new TFS 2015 server I want to create a webpage where you can see a history of warning counts and code coverage for each build. How do I get the information how many warnings occurred and how much code of the build was covered with unit tests? I have tried finding this by getting Builds via the `BuildHttpClient` but when debugging through the Build class I have not found any property that has that information. Here is the code how I get the builds:

```
    public static Build[] GetRunningBuilds(this BuildHttpClient buildServer, string collectionName)
    {
        return buildServer.GetBuildsAsync(collectionName, statusFilter: BuildStatus.InProgress).Result.ToArray();
    }

    public static Build[] GetFailedBuilds(this BuildHttpClient buildServer, string collectionName)
    {
        var builds = buildServer.GetBuildsAsync(collectionName, statusFilter: BuildStatus.Completed, resultFilter: BuildResult.Failed).Result.ToList();
        builds.AddRange(buildServer.GetBuildsAsync(collectionName, statusFilter: BuildStatus.Completed, resultFilter: BuildResult.PartiallySucceeded).Result);

        return builds.OrderBy(b=>b.FinishTime).ToArray();
    }

    public static DefinitionReference[] GetBuildDefinitions(this BuildHttpClient buildServer, string collectionName)
    {
        var buildDefinitions = buildServer.GetDefinitionsAsync(project: collectionName).Result.ToList();
        return buildDefinitions.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Are you using XAML builds or the new build system?

Comment: The new build system.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "GetBuildCodeCoverageAsync" method in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi to get code coverage information.

```
ITestManagementHttpClient.GetBuildCodeCoverageAsync(string, int, int, object, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
```

> System.Threading.Tasks.Task>
>   GetBuildCodeCoverageAsync(string project, int buildId, int flags,
>   [object userState = null], [System.Threading.CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken = null])
>       Member of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.ITestManagementHttpClient
>
> Summary: Sends REST based msg to Server for getting Code Coverage
>   object for build based on buildId and flags This API can be consumed
>   in GET process.

For the flags information, refer to this link for details: [Get code coverage data for a build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/code-coverage#get-code-coverage-data-for-a-build).

Comment: Is there a reason why the TFS portal would show results but the response from `GetBuildCodeCoverageAsync` would be an empty list?

Answer (score 0):

To get code-coverage, you need to use the `CoverageAnalysisManager`.

Like this:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfs_server_here:8080/tfs/something_here"));
ITestManagementService tcm = (ITestManagementService) tfs.GetService(typeof(ITestManagementService));
ITestManagementTeamProject testManagementTeamProject = tcm.GetTeamProject("team_name_here");
ICoverageAnalysisManager coverageAnalysisManager = testManagementTeamProject.CoverageAnalysisManager;
IBuildCoverage[] queryBuildCoverage = coverageAnalysisManager.QueryBuildCoverage(build.Uri.ToString(), CoverageQueryFlags.Modules);
```